# Need to close InputStream after putObject() for Amazon Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it needed to close the passed in InputStream on the `putObject` method of the Amazon Java SDK for S3?

Their [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object) only shows usage with a File, but not with an InputStream. The [Javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-) also does not indicate if it is needed or not.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Since the contract for `Closeable.close()` is that it is idempotent, I'd say when in doubt, err on the side of caution. By `finally` closing it, you handle both the happy path and the case when `putObject` throws `AmazonServiceException`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the S3 client, a provided `InputStream` is not closed by the call.

The relevant code is [S3DataSource.Utils.cleanupDataSource()](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3DataSource.java#L43), which is called in a `finally` block for `PutObject` and similar calls.

This is a general Java convention, but since it's not documented there's no guarantee that it will remain this way. Perhaps file feedback?